# Which module to install to fix "module QtQuick.Controls.Styles is not installed" error for Yocto?

Tags: qt, qml, yocto, bitbake, qtquickcontrols

I've successfully built a Yocto image for the RPi2 following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@shigmas/yocto-pi-and-qt-e9f2df38a610). I decided to expand the QML demo and try some of the Qt quick styles (`import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4`).

Here is the `bb` file for the image

```
# Pulled from a mix of different images:
include recipes-core/images/rpi-basic-image.bb

# This image is a little more full featured, and includes wifi
# support, provided you have a raspberrypi3
inherit linux-raspberrypi-base

SUMMARY = "The minimal image that can run Qt5 applications"
LICENSE = "MIT"

# depend on bcm2835, which will bring in rpi-config
DEPENDS += "bcm2835-bootfiles"

MY_TOOLS = " \
    qtbase \
    qtbase-dev \
    qtbase-mkspecs \
    qtbase-plugins \
    qtbase-tools \
"

MY_PKGS = " \
    qt3d \
    qt3d-dev \
    qt3d-mkspecs \
    qtcharts \
    qtcharts-dev \
    qtcharts-mkspecs \
    qtconnectivity-dev \
    qtconnectivity-mkspecs \
    qtquickcontrols2 \
    qtquickcontrols2-dev \
    qtquickcontrols2-mkspecs \
    qtdeclarative \
    qtdeclarative-dev \
    qtdeclarative-mkspecs \
    qtgraphicaleffects \
    qtgraphicaleffects-dev \
"

MY_FEATURES = " \
    linux-firmware-bcm43430 \
    bluez5 \
    i2c-tools \
    python-smbus \
    bridge-utils \
    hostapd \
    dhcp-server \
    iptables \
    wpa-supplicant \
"

DISTRO_FEATURES_append += " bluez5 bluetooth wifi"

IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " \
    ${MY_TOOLS} \
    ${MY_PKGS} \
    ${MY_FEATURES} \
    basicquick \
"
# Qt >5.7 doesn't ship with fonts, so these need to be added explicitely
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = "\
    ttf-dejavu-sans \
    ttf-dejavu-sans-mono \
    ttf-dejavu-sans-condensed \
    ttf-dejavu-serif \
    ttf-dejavu-serif-condensed \
    ttf-dejavu-common \
"
```

and the `bb` file for the demo itself

```
SUMMARY = "Simple Qt5 Quick application"
SECTION = "examples"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"

# I want to make sure these get installed too.
DEPENDS += "qtbase qtdeclarative qtquickcontrols2"

SRCREV = "${AUTOREV}"

# GitLab own repo
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "f2dcc13cda523e9aa9e8e1db6752b3dfaf4b531bfc9bb8e272eb3bfc5974738a"
SRC_URI = "git://git@gitlab.com:/some-repo.git;protocol=ssh"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

require recipes-qt/qt5/qt5.inc

do_install() {
      install -d ${D}${bindir}
      install -m 0755 BasicQuick ${D}${bindir}
}
```

Upon execution I got the error

```
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
qrc:/main.qml:24 Type Page2 unavailable
qrc:/Page2.qml:4 module "QtQuick.Controls.Styles" is not installed
```

with `Page2` being an item I have defined and used inside `main.qml`. The demo runs without any issues on my PC (custom built Qt 5.9.1) but fails on the RPi2 due to the missing submodule.

Frankly I've never use this submodule before (my custom built Qt 5.9.1 has everything enabled) and I'm not sure what I need include (if `meta-qt5` even provides it) in order to be able to use it on the Yocto system.

Comment: try adding the QML module as well

Comment: What is the exact name? I tried `qtqml` but `bitbake` tells me that there are no build providers for it.

Comment: Btw I'm looking [here](https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/branch/master/layer/meta-qt5/) for modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the mismatch of versions of the Qt Quick Controls package.

You use version 1:

```
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
```

but build version 2:

```
MY_PKGS = " \
    ...
    qtquickcontrols2 \
    ...
```

What you need include in your image is `qtquickcontrols`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install qtquickcontrols-qmlplugins.

Just add to build/local.conf

```
PACKAGECONFIG_append_pn-qtbase = " accessibility"
PACKAGECONFIG_append_pn-qtquickcontrols = " accessibility"

IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " qtdeclarative-qmlplugins qtquickcontrols-qmlplugins"
```

Here is origin manual
https://importgeek.wordpress.com/2018/07/17/module-qtquick-controls-is-not-installed/